XGBRanker grouping and ranking specifics
I have a data frame containing gene-TF pairs with two columns (colA and colB) showing the strength of the interaction. I have another column (colC) with continuous variables where I use it as a sanity check, meaning that higher the value in colC, that gene-gene pair should be ranked higher. Based on that, I am trying to rank these pairs.

I thought XGBRanker would be ideal in this example. When it comes to grouping, I want model to compare each pair with each pair. Since the model requires grouping, I grouped pairs based on unique TF names. In total I had 25-30 groups, I dont think that it is ideal. For the rank column, I split the continuous variable ColC into quartiles and have 3-5 splits.

I am a bit confused since I couldnt find much documentation about XGBRanker. What would be the ideal approach to take it here?
Appreciate any help!
Thanks
I ran the model with default parameters and basic grouping. First ranking didnt make so much sense. I am trying to figure out a better way of performing this.
